# Record sound before it reaches the speaker (record it, not using the mic) in Android

Tags: android

So here is the deal, i have an app that you can use to make music. You press buttons and it plays sounds. Currently i am using default android api for sound recording, which takes the sound from the speaker, records it via the microphone, and then saves it to whatever format I want in the memory. This process produces *.mp3 with very poor quality.

I want to catch the sound before it reaches the speaker and record it then. Something like the radio recording apps. Any ideas and/or links would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think it has been added in the last 2 versions of Android, you should have a look at the release notes.

Comment: The idea of the app is to be accessibly for low end devs, 2.1+ so that wouldn't do me any good, but thanks, I might have a look, for future projects.

Comment: We we soon be in the period where the 2.x branch starts to fall and 4.x is the main branch in terms of marketshare so it would not be totally senseless to base your dev on new 4.x APIs.

Google offers compatibility libraries in order to be able  to use the new developments in old versions of Android but I really doubt that something so low level is in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use MediaRecorder/AudioRecord for this, because there's no way in Android to specify an audio output as an input for a recorder. The way the radio recorders work (if you're talking about FM-radio, and not digital radio) is that a (non-standard) input device has been added from where you can read audio data coming from the FM-radio chip. At least some vendors do this.

Since you want to save the output of just your app (and not any app running on the phone) it's possible to do by taking all the audio you send to your AudioTrack/MediaPlayer and also write it to a file at the same time. You might have to mix the sounds first if you play multiple sounds simultaneously. And if your sounds aren't raw PCM you'll also have to take care of decoding them in your app.